# random number between multiple ranges in c

Tags: c, random

I want to generate a random number between multiple ranges in C. Also I want to take the input from user for the number of ranges. I do have a function for generating random number within one range, can I use that function to generate such multiple ranges? Please Help.

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple ranges?" As in, generate a number that is in either `[1, 4]` or `[6, 7]`, but not `(5, 6)`?

Comment: @DesertIvy Yes exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define a range equal in length to the sum of your ranges, generate a random number in that range, then see in which part it falls. Eg. for ranges (2,5) and (100,200) generate `x` in (0,103), then if it is less than 3, return `2+x` else return `100+x-3`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have a way to generate a random number within one range, you can certainly generate it between two ranges:

First, determine how many possible values there are.

```
int num_values = 1 + range1high - range1low;
num_values += (1 + range2high - range2low);
// continue for additional ranges
```

Next generate a random number between 0 and `num_values`.

Finally, adjust that number based on the base of range 1's low. If it exceeds range 1's high, subtract the size of range 1 and re-base it on range 2. Continue to re-base for additional ranges.

---

The following program has a hard coded sample of generating a number in the ranges [2,5] or [100,200], and an exercise that generates enough data to normally hit every value within the valid ranges. This function could be improved upon significantly, but it works fine for a hard-coded set of ranges:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int randomInRanges()
{
  int range1low = 2,   range1high = 5;
  int range2low = 100, range2high = 200;

  int range1size = 1 + range1high - range1low;
  int range2size = 1 + range2high - range2low;

  int numValues = range1size + range2size;

  int rawRandom = rand() % (numValues);

  /* is the value within range 1? */
  if (rawRandom < range1size) return range1low + rawRandom; /* return a range 1 value */
  rawRandom -= range1size;

  /* is it in range 2? */
  if (rawRandom < range2size) return range2low + rawRandom; /* return a range 2 value */
  rawRandom -= range1size; /* not necessary since we've seen the last range, but part of the pattern */

  printf("Impossible!\n");
  exit(0);
  return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int values[300] = {0, };
  int i;
  /* seed the random number generator */
  srand(time(NULL));

  for (i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
  {
    values[randomInRanges()]++;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 300; ++i)
  {
    if (values[i]) printf("[%d]: %d\n", i, values[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: how to re-base for higher ranges? can you please explain the 're-basing' with an example I am unable to understand it.

Comment: @SouravMandal the same way CiaPan's answer suggests; if the value is greater than the length of the first range, subtract the length of the first range and add the low value of the second range.

Comment: The lower value of the second range is not being included by this method.

Comment: There's an off-by-one error in the example; for my code, `num_values` _should_ get set to `1 + range1high - range1low`. Looking at CiaPan's numbers, assuming the true random number was 6, you would want to select 100. He suggests `100+x-3`, which is `range2low + randomnum = num_values` but like me, he is off by one; there are 4 values in the bottom range.

Comment: but like that the number violates the 2nd range, if we follow the same procedure as suggested by CiaPan

Comment: You just have to make a small adjustment :) Just figure out where the "off by one" is and add/subtract 1.

Comment: I have adjusted something, I am able to generate all the nos except the lower number of each range. please help.

Comment: The example I've added to my answer works; it prints out counters for each number it generated after 10000 loops, and all values in the defined ranges are seen while no external values are seen. The range boundaries are inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest you do is select a range randomly, then, generate the number within that range.

```
srand(time(NULL));
int r = rand() % 3; //supposing we have 3 ranges to choose from
int min;
int max;

switch(r) {
case(0): // [1, 4]
    min = 1;
    max = 4;
case(1): // [6, 7]
    min = 6;
    max = 7;
case(2): // [10, 15]
    min = 10;
    max = 15;
}

int range = max - min;
r = (rand() % range) + min;
```

Comment: If range 1 is 1-2, and range 2 is 4-1000, you would have a whole lot of 1 or 2 values.

Comment: I want to take the number of ranges and min and max for each range as an input